# SailsJS server and HTTPS

Tags: https, socket.io, sails.js

Sails.js integrates node.js http server and socket.io server. How can I change that http server to a https server? Similarly, can I add SSL to encrypt socket messages as well? If yes, what should I do? Is there any module I can add to do either or both of them?

Answer (score 2):

To add https to Sails.js you have to self signed create an SSL certificat (or buy one ^^) and configure config/local.js

```
   http : {
    serverOptions : {
      key  : require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/server.key'),
      cert : require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/server.crt')
    }
  },
  ssl  : {
    key  : require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/server.key'),
    cert : require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/../ssl/server.crt')
  },
  port: process.env.PORT || 443,
```

I create a ssl folder at sails root folder with all certificate files.